# How to upload download files to amazon s3 bucket with my current code

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, download, upload

I have this spring boot application that uses conventional way of document upload and download (By creating a folder on server), it takes files from html as multipart and we also have our android application web services which sends the data to rest controllers as base64 then converts it into byte format.
Please tell me how can I implement the same code to s3 bucket with minimal changes.

Service implementation class

```
package com.erp.serviceimpl;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import com.erp.model.Document;
import com.erp.repository.DocumentRepository;
import com.erp.service.DocumentService;

@Service
public class DocumentServiceImpl implements DocumentService {

    @Autowired
    DocumentRepository documentrepository;

    // Save the uploaded file to this folder
    private static String UPLOADED_FOLDER = "s3://elasticbeanstalk-ap-south-1-461760552509/imagesUpload/";

    @Override
    public boolean uploadUserImage(MultipartFile file, Document document) {
        System.out.println("pooja" + file);
        boolean status = false;
        if (document != null) {
            document.setDate(new Date());
            document.setTurbine_id(document.getTurbine_id());
            Document documentImage = documentrepository.save(document);
            if (documentImage != null) {

                try {
                    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                    Path path = Paths.get(UPLOADED_FOLDER + document.getDocId() + "_" + file.getOriginalFilename());
                    Files.write(path, bytes);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                documentImage.setUploadImagesPath(document.getDocId() + "_" + file.getOriginalFilename());
                documentrepository.save(documentImage);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return status;
    }


    @Override
    public List<Document> getAllImages() {
        return documentrepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Document> findAllByTurbine_id(int turbine_id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Iterable<Document> itr = documentrepository.findAllByTurbine_id(turbine_id);
        return (List<Document>)itr;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean uploadUserWebServiceImage(Document document) {
        boolean status = false;
        if (document != null) {
            document.setDate(new Date());
            document.setTurbine_id(document.getTurbine_id());
            Document documentImage = documentrepository.save(document);
            if (documentImage != null) {
                try {
                    String[] img = document.getImageBase().split(",");
                    byte[] imageByte = Base64.decodeBase64(img[1]);
                    Path path = Paths.get(UPLOADED_FOLDER + documentImage.getDocId() + "_" + document.getUploadImagesPath());
                    Files.write(path, imageByte);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                documentImage.setUploadImagesPath(documentImage.getDocId() + "_" + document.getUploadImagesPath());
                documentrepository.save(documentImage);
                status = true;
                return status;
            }
        }
        return status;
    }

}
```

Controller Class.

```
package com.erp.controller;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import com.erp.model.Document;
import com.erp.service.DocumentService;
import com.erp.service.EmployeeService;
import com.erp.service.TurbineService;
import com.erp.utils.IConstant;

@Controller
@ComponentScan
public class DocumentController {

    @Autowired
    DocumentService documentService;

    @Autowired
    TurbineService turbineService;

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeService;

    @GetMapping("/addDocument/{turbine_id}")
    public String newDocument(@PathVariable Integer turbine_id, Model model) {
        Document document = new Document();
        document.setTurbine_id(turbine_id);
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        model.addAttribute("employee", employeeService.findEmployeeByUsername(auth.getName()));
        model.addAttribute("turbine", turbineService.findTurbine(turbine_id));
        model.addAttribute("addDocument", document);
        model.addAttribute("viewDocuments", (ArrayList<Document>) documentService.findAllByTurbine_id(turbine_id));
        return "turbine-documents";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/documentUpload", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    private String saveUploadImages(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
            @ModelAttribute("Document") Document document, ModelMap model,
            final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        boolean status = documentService.uploadUserImage(file, document);
        if (status) {
            model.addAttribute(IConstant.MESSAGE, IConstant.UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS_MESSAGE);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", IConstant.UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS_MESSAGE);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("alertClass", "alert-success");
        } else {
            model.addAttribute(IConstant.MESSAGE, IConstant.UPLOAD_IMAGE_FAILURE_MESSAGE);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", IConstant.UPLOAD_IMAGE_FAILURE_MESSAGE);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("alertClass", "alert-danger");
        }

        return "redirect:/addDocument/" + document.getTurbine_id();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloadFile(@RequestParam("uploadImagesPath") String uploadImagesPath)
            throws IOException {
        String filename = "s3://elasticbeanstalk-ap-south-1-461760552509/imagesUpload/" + uploadImagesPath;
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        InputStream inputImage = new FileInputStream(filename);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
        int l = inputImage.read(buffer);
        while (l >= 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, l);
            l = inputImage.read(buffer);
        }
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
        headers.set("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        headers.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + uploadImagesPath + "");
        return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(outputStream.toByteArray(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Thymeleaf page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title>Documents</title>
<meta
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"
    name="viewport" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/ctmi_favicon.png"
    th:href="@{/images/ctmi_favicon.png}" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/ctmi_favicon-57x57.png"
    th:href="@{/images/ctmi_favicon-57x57.png}" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72"
    href="images/ctmi_favicon-72x72.png"
    th:href="@{/images/ctmi_favicon-72x72.png}" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114"
    href="images/ctmi_favicon-114x114.png"
    th:href="@{/images/ctmi_favicon-114x114.png}" />

<!-- css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"
    th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css"
    th:href="@{/css/font-awesome.min.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css"
    th:href="@{/css/jquery-ui.min.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"
    th:href="@{/css/style.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css"
    th:href="@{/css/responsive.css}" />


<!--[if IE]>
        <script src="js/html5shiv.js" th:src="@{/js/html5shiv.js}" ></script>
    <![endif]-->

<!-- js -->
<!-- js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"
    th:src="@{/js/jquery.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"
    th:src="@{/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"
    th:src="@{/js/jquery-ui.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"
    th:src="@{/js/custom.js}"></script>
</head>

<body class="alBody">
    <!-- Preloader -->
    <div class="preLoader"></div>

    <!-- Header -->
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="hdrLogo">
                <img src="images/chola_turbo_logo.png"
                    th:src="@{/images/chola_turbo_logo.png}" alt="cholaturbo Logo"
                    class="logoDefault" />
            </div>
            <div class="hdrRight">
                <div class="hdrrInr">
                    <div class="hdrrLeft">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="logoutIcn">
                                <a href="#" th:href="@{/page/home}">
                                    <i class="fa fa-home fa-7x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </a>

                            </li>
                            <li class="logoutIcn">
                                <a href="#" th:href="@{/employee/edit/{employee_id}(employee_id=${employee.employee_id})}" >
                                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-7x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </a>

                            </li>

                            <li class="logoutIcn"><a href="/logout"><i
                                    class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Body Content Sec -->
    <section class="bodyCnt">
        <!-- Top Bread Sec -->
        <div class="topBread">
            <div class="container">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="#"
                        th:href="@{/client/{client_id}(client_id=${turbine.client_id})}">BACK</a></li>
                    <li class="active">Documents</li>
                </ol>
                <div class="addProj"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Main body page -->
        <div class="mbSec">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="dbWrap clearfix">

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="bsSgl">
                            <div class="bsInr">

                                <div class="dbsHead">
                                    <h4>Turbine Details</h4>
                                </div>

                                <ul class="side-menu">
                                    <li><a href="turbine-details-new.html"
                                        th:href="@{/turbine/{turbine_id}(turbine_id=${addDocument.turbine_id})}">Turbine
                                            Details </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="turbine-engneer-assigned.html"
                                        th:href="@{/AddAssignTurbine/{turbine_id}(turbine_id=${addDocument.turbine_id})}">Engneer
                                            Assigned</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="turbine-site-report.html"
                                        th:href="@{/addAddService/{turbine_id}(turbine_id=${addDocument.turbine_id})}">Site
                                            Report</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="turbine-site-readings.html"
                                        th:href="@{/readingPage/{turbine_id}(turbine_id=${addDocument.turbine_id})}">Site
                                            Reading</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="turbine-material.html"
                                        th:href="@{/material/{turbine_id}(turbine_id=${addDocument.turbine_id})}">Materials And Spares</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="turbine-documents.html"
                                        th:href="@{/addDocument/{turbine_id}(turbine_id=${addDocument.turbine_id})}"
                                        class="active">Documents</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="turbine-drawings.html"
                                        th:href="@{/addDrawing/{turbine_id}(turbine_id=${addDocument.turbine_id})}">Drawings</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="turbine-ta-da.html"
                                        th:href="@{/AddDailyAllowance/{turbine_id}(turbine_id=${addDocument.turbine_id})}">TA
                                            DA Bill</a></li>
                                    <li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ADMIN')"><a
                                        href="turbine-man-days-expenses.html"
                                        th:href="@{/ManDays/{turbine_id}(turbine_id=${addDocument.turbine_id})}">
                                            Man Days Expenses</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="turbine-client-delay.html"
                                        th:href="@{/addClientDelay/{turbine_id}(turbine_id=${addDocument.turbine_id})}">Client
                                            Delay</a></li>
                                    <li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ADMIN')"><a
                                        href="turbine-client-requests.html"
                                        th:href="@{/AddClientResponse/{turbine_id}(turbine_id=${addDocument.turbine_id})}">Client
                                            Requests</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="turbine-generate-report"
                                        th:href="@{/generateReportPage/{turbine_id}(turbine_id=${addDocument.turbine_id})}">Generate
                                            Report</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- end left bar -->

                    <div class="col-md-9 bsSgl">
                        <div class="bsInr">
                            <div class="dbsHead">
                                <h4>Documents</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div th:if="${message}" th:text="${message}"
                                th:class="${'alert ' + alertClass}"></div>
                            <form class="row" action="#" th:action="@{/documentUpload}"
                                th:object="${addDocument}" method="post"
                                enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <div class="bsMtr">
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <div class="snglInpt">
                                            <input type="file" name="file"
                                                placeholder="Upload Image" th:required="required" /> <input
                                                type="hidden" th:field="*{turbine_id}" name="turbine_id"
                                                id="turbine_id" placeholder="Turbine Id" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clearfix"></div>

                        <div class="bsInr mrg-top-20">
                            <div class="bsMtr">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table" id="doc_list">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>

                                                <td>TurbineId</td>
                                                <td>Image</td>
                                                <td>Date</td>
                                                <td>Download Image</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr th:each="viewDocument : ${viewDocuments}">
                                                <td th:text="${viewDocument.docId}"></td>
                                                <td th:text="${viewDocument.uploadImagesPath}"></td>
                                                <td th:text="${viewDocument.date}"></td>
                                                <td><a
                                                    th:href="@{|/download?uploadImagesPath=${viewDocument.uploadImagesPath}|}"><span
                                                        th:text="${viewDocument.uploadImagesPath}"></span></a></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    <!-- end col md 12 -->

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <p>Copyright © 2018 cholaturbo</p>
        </div>
    </footer>


</body>
</html>
```

Rest controller for android:

```
package com.erp.webService;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.erp.model.Document;
import com.erp.service.DocumentService;
import com.erp.utils.IConstant;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class DocumentWebService {

    @Autowired
    DocumentService documentService;

    private static String UPLOADED_FOLDER = "//var//sentora//hostdata//cholaerp//public_html//imagesUpload//";

    @RequestMapping(value = "uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> saveUserImage(@RequestBody Document document) throws IOException {
        int turbine_id = document.getTurbine_id();
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        boolean documents = documentService.uploadUserWebServiceImage(document);
        if (documents) {
            List<Document> list = documentService.findAllByTurbine_id(turbine_id);
            for (Document doc : list) {
                doc.setImageBase(null);
                doc.setUploadImagesPath(doc.getUploadImagesPath());
            }
            map.put(IConstant.RESPONSE, IConstant.RESPONSE_SUCCESS_MESSAGE);
            map.put(IConstant.MESSAGE, IConstant.UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS_MESSAGE);
            map.put(IConstant.DATA, list);
        } else {
            map.put(IConstant.RESPONSE, IConstant.RESPONSE_NO_DATA_MESSAGE);
            map.put(IConstant.MESSAGE, IConstant.UPLOAD_IMAGE_FAILURE_MESSAGE);
        }
        return map;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/downloadFile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloadFile(@RequestParam("uploadImagesPath") String uploadImagesPath)
            throws IOException {
        String filename = "https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com//s3//buckets//elasticbeanstalk-ap-south-1-461760552509//?region=ap-south-1&tab=overview//imagesUpload//" + uploadImagesPath;
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        InputStream inputImage = new FileInputStream(filename);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
        int l = inputImage.read(buffer);
        while (l >= 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, l);
            l = inputImage.read(buffer);
        }
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
        headers.set("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        headers.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + uploadImagesPath + "");
        return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(outputStream.toByteArray(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/getAllImages", produces = "application/json")
    public List<Document> getAllImages() {
        return (List<Document>) documentService.getAllImages();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/getAllDocument/{turbine_id}", produces = "application/json")
    public List<Document> getAllByTurbineId(@PathVariable(value = "turbine_id") int turbine_id)  {
        return (List<Document>) documentService.findAllByTurbine_id(turbine_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your first post on Stack Overflow. One idea that we have here is to provide the minimum code sample to show the problem. Try paring down your provided code to the minimum necessary too show the problem.

Comment: Sure, will keep in mind fron next time

Comment: For tips on how to ask a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/)?  It does exactly what you need and you wont have to write *any* of that code.

Assuming maven, Spring Boot and Spring Data (let me know if you are using something else):-

> pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- HSQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>content-s3-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-content-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>content-rest-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-content-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ... 
<dependencies>
```

Update your entity with the managed Spring Content annotations.

> Document.java

```
@Entity    
public class Document {
  ...existing fields...

  @ContentId
  private String contentId;

  @ContentLength
  private Long contentLen;

  @MimeType
  private String mimeType;

  ...getters and setters...
}
```

Create a connection to your S3 store.  The S3 Store has been implemented to use a SimpleStorageResourceLoader so this bean will ultimately be used by your store.

> StoreConfig.java

```
  @Configuration
  @EnableS3Stores
  public class S3Config {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public Region region() {
        return Region.getRegion(Regions.fromName(System.getenv("AWS_REGION")));
    }

    @Bean
    public BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials() {
        return new BasicAWSCredentials(env.getProperty("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"), env.getProperty("AWS_SECRET_KEY"));
    }

    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 client(AWSCredentials awsCredentials) {
        AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials);
        amazonS3Client.setRegion(region());
        return amazonS3Client;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleStorageResourceLoader simpleStorageResourceLoader(AmazonS3 client) {
        return new SimpleStorageResourceLoader(client);
    }
  }
```

Define a Store typed to Document - as that is what you are associating content with.

> DocumentContentStore.java

```
@StoreRestResource(path="documentContent")
public interface DocumentStore extends ContentStore<Document, String> {
}
```

When you run this you also need to set the bucket for your store.  This can be done by specifying `spring.content.s3.bucket` in application.properties/yaml or by setting the `AWS_BUCKET` environment variable.

This is enough to create a REST-based content service for storing content in S3 and associating that content with your `Document` entity.  Spring Content will see the Store interface and the S3 dependencies.  Assume you want to store content in S3 and inject an implementation of your interface for you.  Meaning you dont have to implement it yourself.  You will be able to store content by POSTing a multipart-form-data request to:

```
POST /documentcontent/{documentId}
```

and fetching it again with:

```
GET /documentscontent/{documentId}
```

(the service supports full CRUD BTW and video streaming in case that might be important).

You'll see that Spring Content associates content with your entity by managing the content related annotations for you.

This can be used with or without Spring Data REST.  The dependencies are a little different depending.  I've assumed you are NOT using Spring Data REST.  Let me know if that isn't the case and I'll update the example.

There is a video of this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbDaONWWT3s) - the demo starts about half way through.  It uses the Filesystem module not S3 but they are interchangeable.  Just need to pick the right dependencies for the type of store you are using.  S3 in your case.

HTH

Comment: Hi paul thanks a lot for your answer. 
Now I am able to upload my documents to s3.It works file when I run it on localhost but when I run it on elastic beanstalk it doesn't upload anything to my bucket, the download is still working but I am not able to upload anything.
I have been stuck on this for 2 days, please let me know if you can help.

Comment: I forgot to mention actually you need to set the bucket to upload into by setting the 'AWS_BUCKET' environment variable.  I have updated the answer accordingly.  Anyway, this may be why SC Filesystem is working (because it uses a temporary filesystem) and SC S3 is not.  Give that a whirl and let me know.